# Rail + Compass sprite generation gives wrong image path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

In my Rails 3.2.1 application I am using compass(0.12.alpha.4) to create sprites:

```
@import compass

@import "../images/category-icons/type/*.png"
@include all-type-sprites
//+all-type-sprites
```

The sprite image was genereated correctly, sitting in *app/assets/images/category-icons/type-sa69c4767de.png*

However the stylesheet generated is wrong. It points to `/assets/../images/category-icons/type-sa69c4767de.png`. It merely appends `assets` to the path. It works outside of Rails, so I think it has something to do with asset pipeline. What should I configure for this to work properly?

Comment: What do you have in your compass config.rb for `http_generated_images_path`? I had a similar issue and it was resolved by setting the http config paths.

Comment: I don't see that config at all, and that's not related to this path problem. But thanks for letting me know, as I think it is a good thing to set, so the genereated file can reside outside the asset directory (which annoys for me).

Comment: I agree. Moving the generated sprite sheet outside `app/assets` means I don't have to try to exclude those files from version control.

Don't forget to add the new path to rails assets paths.

`generated_images_dir = "tmp/sass-cache/sprites"` in `config/compass.rb`.
`config.assets.paths += "tmp/sass-cache/sprites" in `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using [`compass-rails`](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails)? It ensures proper integration with the asset pipeline.

> Since Compass v0.12, this adapter is the only way to install compass into your rails application.

Don't use a relative path to the source images. Image path references already search through the asset load path. Rails is configured to include `app/assets/images` in the asset load path by default.

Change the import to:

`@import "category-icons/type/*.png"`

Comment: thanks, the relative path is from the designer using Middleman. Will remember to convert this part next time. Note that compass-rails and compass 0.12.alpha.4 are interchangeable.